# Where can I find a dataset of language phoneme sets?

Tags: phonetics, phonemes, phonetic-symbols

I'm looking for a dataset of phoneme sets for the most widely spoken languages. Something like the sort of thing available here:

http://web.phonetik.uni-frankfurt.de/upsid.html

though the data there is not conveniently available nor is it particularly comprehensive for widely spoken languages (for example, it does have English as far as I can see). Even better if there are frequency statistics for the phonemes. Any ideas?

Comment: How many of the "most widely spoken languages" do you want? 5, 10, 50? If it's around 10, which languages are you missing (apart from English)? I can see German, Hindi, Telugu, French, Spanish, Mandarin, so most of them seem to be available. Also, what format do you want? Listing all the phonemes of a language as they did on the website you indicated seems pretty convenient to me. Although I suppose it might depend on what you want to do with them.

Comment: As for other sources, Wikipedia isn't that bad on most languages and usually indicates academic sources where you can check. In addition, there's the IPA Handbook with phoneme inventories for a number of languages and they keep adding more languages and dialects through articles in the IPA journal.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

http://phoible.org/

It includes the phoneme inventories you mention above, converted into Unicode IPA, and many more languages.

Comment: Thanks! I can't really access any of the inventories I tried in [this list](http://phoible.org/inventories). If I click on the language code I get referred to Ethnologue and if I click on the inventory number I just get a database entry without phoneme inventory. Am I doing something wrong here?